# Nontrivial microbundles

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I'm looking for easy examples of nontrivial microbundles (meaning: microbundles which are not stably isomorphic to the trivial microbundle). Some examples on $S^1$ or even $S^n$ would be really nice!!

Comment: For each $k > 0$ there's a rank-$k$ non-orientable vector bundle on $S^1$

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if the underlying microbundles are non-isomorphic?

Comment: They are all stably isomorphic, since $(\mathbf{R}^k, \text{flip}) \oplus (\mathbf{R}, \text{id}) \cong (\mathbf{R}^{k+1}, \text{flip})$.